# Schematic symbol: broken cylinder

Tags: symbol

What is this symbol?

I couldn't decide whether it's a solder bridge or not.

[image: schematic of a Low noise diode laser current controller]

Answer (score 12):

That's a coaxial cable. The "broken" section in the middle symbolizes "very long".

Answer (score 5):

Given that it feeds the laser diode and must not be a short circuit the symbol seems to represent a coaxial cable connection. It looks a little childish because the perspective is wrong at one end or the other.

Comment: it is not supposed to be a representation of a 3D object view ... because the RF connector symbols are used, it is unclear if the coax cable is soldered into the circuit, or if connectors are used